# Accessing the property of a model in ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having problems accessing one of the properties of the model I am passing a View.

The model is defined like this:

```
public class ProductBasket
{
    public ProductBasket()
    {
        Products = new List<ProductConfiguration>();
        Errors = new List<string>();
    }
    public List<ProductConfiguration> Products { get; set; }
    public List<string> Errors { get; set; }
}
```

In my view the model directive is declared like this:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.Product.ProductBasket
```

I am unable to access the `Products` property in a `foreach` loop. In VisualStudio when I hover of the `Model` variable in the loop it shows:

```
List<MyApp.ViewModels.Product.ProductConfiguration> 
WebViewPage<List<MyApp.ViewModels.Product.ProductConfiguration>>.Model { get; }
```

This is the *previous* model I was using - I don't know why this is there?

**What I have done**

Instinct tells me I should be able to access the Products property with `Model.Products` (please tell me if this is incorrect), but I don't understand why the view isn't being passed a `ProductBasket`?

Comment: Check if you pass the correct model in a controller and yes you should be able to access products with Model.Products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are passing a collection of `ProductConfiguration` class objects to the view. Make sure you are sending a single object of `ProductBasket` class to your view from your action method

```
public ActionResult Something()
{
  var vm = new ProductBasket();

 //The below line is hard coded for demo. You may replace with actual list from db.
  vm.Products.Add(new ProductConfiguration { Id=1,Name="test"});

  return View(vm);
}
```

Assuming your `ProductConfiguration` class has an Id and Name property.

And your view should be bound to `ProductBasket`

```
@model YourNameSpaceHere.ProductBasket
<h1>Products</h1>

@foreach(var product in Model.Products)
{
  <h2>@product.Name</h2>
}
```

Comment: My mistake, like you suggested I was passing the old model to the View. 
Confusingly, I have now made sure I am returning a ProductBasket and built the project but I am still getting the same List<MyApp.ViewModels.Product.ProductConfiguration> ??

Comment: If you hover over Model.Products, you will get that and that is correct.

Comment: I realise that however I am just hovering over Model

Comment: That means you are sending the wrong model to the view from your action method. As I mentioned in the answer, make sure it is single object of productbasket class. Try the code I posted