# Null TempData when passing data from controller to view MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag, tempdata

I have the following class in a Controller passing data to a View:

```
public ActionResult ControllerToView(){
    ...
    TempData["example"] = "this is a message!";
    ...
    return Redirect("http://myViewPageLink");
}
```

In my View, I am trying to access the TempData dictionary with:

```
@if(myCondition){
    var test = TempData["example"];
    <p>@test</p>
}
```

"myCondition" is always satisfied, but the TempData dictionary is always empty. Any ideas why? Is there any aditional code I have to write in order to make TempData available in the view?

It might be useful information that before calling my controller method I have an ajax request to another method in the same controller.

Comment: You're not returning a view, you are redirecting.  The redirect triggers an entirely different controller action with it's own `TempData` dictionary.

Comment: So isn't it possible to pass TempData that way? Any suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: Look at this article see if it helps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629247/accessing-the-property-of-a-model-in-asp-net-mvc-view

Comment: Tempdata life time is only for one request.In other words it exists between two successive request. So if you have a request in between, it may get nulled out.

Comment: or you can use session as : Session["example"] = "this is a message!";
And retrieve value as: Session["example"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should know that [`TempDataDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary(v=vs.118).aspx) used for short-term instance. Its value available during current & subsequent request when the next request surely redirects to next view (suitable for one-time messages). Any value you've assigned to `TempDataDictionary` **will be discarded after completion of subsequent request**, as "normal read".

So that your current request consists of this sequence:

1. Request => ActionResult (ControllerToView)
2. Set `TempDataDictionary`
3. Response => RedirectResult
4. Request => ViewResult  ==> the `TempDataDictionary` content may discarded here if no `Keep` or `Peek` method used to persist data
5. Response => View (with `TempDataDictionary` is empty)

Hence the correct way to use `TempDataDictionary` is passing value directly to view in current request or using redirect to another controller action method as subsequent request, as this example:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ControllerToView()
{
    ...
    TempData["example"] = "this is a message!";
    ...
    // returning view counts as providing response
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@if (myCondition)
{
    var test = TempData["example"]; // showing message
    <p>@test</p>
}
```

The request sequence for above example is given below:

1. Request => ActionResult (ControllerToView)
2. Set `TempDataDictionary`
3. Response => View (`TempDataDictionary` is not empty)

If you use `RedirectResult` then trying to read/display value in `TempData` without specifying the 'next action', it considered as "normal read" & not persisted for next request. The 'next action' you can use: `Keep` or `Peek` (either in view or controller action):

```
// Keep
var test = TempData["example"];
TempData.Keep("example");

// Peek
var test = TempData.Peek("example");
```

NB: If you want setting values to be persist across multiple requests, I strongly prefer [`HttpSessionState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// set session state
Session["example"] = "[any value]";

// read in another request
var testing = Session["example"];
```

References:

[Using Tempdata in ASP.NET MVC - Best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422930/using-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-best-practice)

[When to use ViewBag, ViewData, or TempData](http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-3-applications/)