# Integration API Facebook: Having no result found to my page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I already create My Apps in https://developers.facebook.com and I already get my app id and app secret. which i already set to my

client_id = "I hide it first",
client_secret = "I hide it first",

My question is when I run my application their is no result found to my cshtml page.

**loginController :**

```
private Uri RediredtUri

{

    get

    {

        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);

        uriBuilder.Query = null;

        uriBuilder.Fragment = null;

        uriBuilder.Path = Url.Action("FacebookCallback");

        return uriBuilder.Uri;

    }

}




[AllowAnonymous]

public ActionResult Facebook()

{

    var fb = new FacebookClient();

    var loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(new

    {

        client_id = "I hide it first",

        client_secret = "I hide it first",

        redirect_uri= RediredtUri.AbsoluteUri,

        response_type="code",

        scope="email"
    });

    return Redirect(loginUrl.AbsoluteUri);

}




public ActionResult FacebookCallback(string code)

{

    var fb = new FacebookClient();

    dynamic result = fb.Post("oauth/access_token", new

    {

        client_id = "I hide it first",

        client_secret = "I hide it first",

        redirect_uri = RediredtUri.AbsoluteUri,

        code = code

    });

    var accessToken = result.access_token;

    Session["AccessToken"] = accessToken;

    fb.AccessToken = accessToken;

    dynamic me = fb.Get("me?fields=link,first_name,currency,last_name,email,gender,locale,timezone,verified,picture,age_range");

    string email = me.email;

    TempData["email"] = me.email;

    TempData["first_name"] = me.first_name;

    TempData["lastname"] = me.last_name;

    TempData["picture"] = me.picture.data.url;

    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, false);

    return RedirectToAction("Login", "login");

}
```

**Login.cshtml :**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Login with facebook", "Facebook", "login")

<table>

    <tr><td>Email:</td><td><b>@TempData["email"]</b></td></tr>

    <tr><td>First Name:</td><td><b>@TempData["first_name"]</b></td></tr>



    <tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><b>@TempData["lastname"]</b></td></tr>

    <tr><td>Picture:</td><td><b><img src="@TempData["picture"]" /></b></td></tr>



</table>
```

I have sample image.
[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're using FB authentication with SDK similar like [this example](https://gist.github.com/ntotten/4341111). If you're sure that `me.email` contains email data and you get empty values after redirection (note that I found you're using `TempData` to show results in login view page), possibly you need to keep `TempData` contents before redirection using [`TempDataDictionary.Keep()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728654%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method:

```
public ActionResult FacebookCallback(string code)
{
    var fb = new FacebookClient();
    dynamic result = fb.Post("oauth/access_token", new
    {
        client_id = "your_app_id",
        client_secret = "your_app_secret_key",
        redirect_uri = RediredtUri.AbsoluteUri,
        code = code

    });

    var accessToken = result.access_token;
    Session["AccessToken"] = accessToken;

    fb.AccessToken = accessToken;
    dynamic me = fb.Get("me?fields=link,first_name,currency,last_name,email,gender,locale,timezone,verified,picture,age_range");

    string email = me.email;

    TempData["email"] = me.email;

    TempData["first_name"] = me.first_name;

    TempData["lastname"] = me.last_name;

    TempData["picture"] = me.picture.data.url;

    // add this line to keep TempData values when passing to view
    TempData.Keep();

    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, false);
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "login");
}
```

The reason behind `TempDataDictionary.Keep()` usage can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356403/null-tempdata-when-passing-data-from-controller-to-view-mvc).

As a side note, better to use strongly-typed viewmodel properties and assign all values stored at `TempData` into them to avoid losing `TempData` contents when passing to view:

**Model**

```
public class FBUser
{    
    public string Email { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

**Controller Action (Login)**

```
var model = new FBUser();

model.Email = TempData["email"];
// other properties assignment

// other stuff

return View(model);
```

**View**

```
@model FBUser

@Html.ActionLink("Login with Facebook", "Facebook", "login")

<table>
    <tr>
       <td>Email:</td>
       <td>
          <b>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)</b>
       </td>
    </tr>

    <!-- other properties -->

</table>

<!-- other stuff -->
```