# Intermittent results with ASP.NET MVC TempData - sometimes it loses it's value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tempdata

In an ASP.NET MVC app, I have a controller action which calls business layer to add an entity.

If for business reasons, the entity could not be added, an Error property is set to true along with a description.

If true, I set a `TempData` key to the error message and then redirect to a view which has code to display the error stored in `TempData` if it exists. Sometimes the conditional block is shown and sometimes not.

Here is the relevant code in my controller

```
var added = ModelHelper.CreateSessionCode(model);

if(added.Error)
{
    TempData["SessionCodesMessage"] = model.ErrorDescription;
    TempData["MessageClass"] = "alert-danger";
}
else
{
    TempData["SessionCodesMessage"] = "Created session code";
    TempData["MessageClass"] = "alert-success";
}

return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Then in my view I have this code:

```
@if (TempData["SessionCodesMessage"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert @TempData["MessageClass"] alert-dismissable" style="margin-top: 8px;">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        @(TempData["SessionCodesMessage"])
    </div>
}
```

And it seems to be inconsistent when the message is displayed or not. Could this be a browser cache issue or similar? From stepping through the code I can confirm that the execution goes into both controller conditional blocks depending on the result of adding the entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so, `TempData` is like `ViewData` but with a difference. It can contain data between two successive requests, but after that they are destroyed.

If you want to keep TempData value then you can use [Keep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ee703522(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

```
TempData.Keep()
```

In your case:

```
var added = ModelHelper.CreateSessionCode(model);

if(added.Error)
{
    TempData["SessionCodesMessage"] = model.ErrorDescription;
    TempData.Keep("SessionCodesMessage");
    TempData["MessageClass"] = "alert-danger";
    TempData.Keep("MessageClass");
}
else
{
    TempData["SessionCodesMessage"] = "Created session code";
    TempData.Keep("SessionCodesMessage");
    TempData["MessageClass"] = "alert-success";
    TempData.Keep("MessageClass");
}

return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

OR

You can also use [Peek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.peek?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) if you want to be explicit about every time you want to retrieve it without having it deleted.

```
var added = ModelHelper.CreateSessionCode(model);

if(added.Error)
{
    //second request, PEEK value so it is not deleted at the end of the request
    TempData["SessionCodesMessage"]; = "Created session code";
    object sessioncodevalue= TempData.Peek("SessionCodesMessage");
    TempData["MessageClass"]; = "alert-success";
    object messageclassvalue= TempData.Peek("MessageClass");
}
else
{
    //second request, PEEK value so it is not deleted at the end of the request
    TempData["SessionCodesMessage"]; = "Created session code";
    object sessioncodevalue= TempData.Peek("SessionCodesMessage");
    TempData["MessageClass"]; = "alert-success";
    object messageclassvalue= TempData.Peek("MessageClass");
}

return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

You can use `Peek` when you always want to retain the value for another request. And use `Keep` when retaining the value depends on additional logic.

You can refer to this article for more information on these functions and how you can use them in your `View`: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ansh06031982/using-tempdata-peek-and-keep-in-Asp-Net-mvc/

Comment: I understand your answer, but I am setting in one request (one controller action) and trying to read from inside the redirect - so this is just 1 successive request

Comment: @andrewb Well, `ViewBag` and `ViewData` are used to pass the data from Controller action to View and `TempData` is used to pass the data from action to another action or one Controller to another Controller. Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356403/null-tempdata-when-passing-data-from-controller-to-view-mvc