# Error when trying to retrieve from TempData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, tempdata

I have a C# asp.net MVC application hosted in Azure. Not always, but sometimes, after a deploy, I face an odd error, that I believe is caused by `TempData`. Restarting the site fixes the issue.

At the end of a controller method, I have the following pattern:

```
TempData["sampleData"] = sampleData;

return RedirectToAction("DownloadSampleData"....
```

Then, at the start of `DownloadSampleData` I have:

```
 var sampleData = TempData["sampleData"] as SampleDataDto;
```

The error that is received is:

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

And the line it points to being the issue is:

`var sampleData = TempData["sampleData"] as SampleDataDto;`

If the site is restarted, the issue seems to go away. This does not happen every time a deploy takes place.

What I am hoping to learn more about here is, how is `TempData` initiated? Would I be correct in assuming the error is because `TempData` is not available at that point, and therefore causes the Object Reference error?

Any thoughts on what could cause this are appreciated as I cannot seem to find anything relevant through Google searches.

Comment: I think tempdata can only be accessed in one consecutive request, if you want to keep it you need to use tempdata.keep

Comment: The code above does work. It is just that sometimes, after a deploy, it errors when it tries to extract the data from TempData. Restarting the site fixes it. Also, the error is specific to the line where it tries to extract the data from it, not the lines after where it then tries to use the extracted object, which makes me think the error is with TempData itself not being initialised, or similar.

Comment: Tempdata was kept only up to one consecutive request after that it is disposed. that could be the reason for null reference exception
try using TempData.Keep("sampleData"), and check if it generate error again, but then you need to manually clear it when its not needed

Comment: I can try that, but with the error being quite sporadic, it is hard to test. Would you not expect though, that if a key didn't exist in TempData, it would not produce the error it is? Would it not fail after, with the same error, when it tried to use the null object?

Comment: For example, if I remove the addition of sampleData to TempData, it errors, but not on the line mentioned in the question, it fails after, because there is nothing to extract from TempData with the name sampleData, so the variable is null.

Comment: You are trying to save `sampleData` to `TempData["sampleDate"]` and retrieving it from `sampleData`. It is completely a different key, hence null reference error.

Comment: @HarshitaSingh-MSFT sorry - a typo. I have updated. As I mentioned, a restart with no code changes fixes this issue. The code is not the problem here, at least, not on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that this is the actual code that you are using. Please note that you are trying to save variable `sampleData` value to `TempData["sampleDate"]` and retrieving it from `sampleData`. It is completely a different key, hence the null reference error.

Comment: Sorry, a typo on my part. As the questions states, a restart of the site fixes the issue. As far as I can see, the code is not the problem here, as it works just fine after a restart. To add, if you mock this up, the null reference would not be hit on that line, it would be hit when you tried to use something on the variable, that was null. So I am not sure why trying to extract from TempData would cause that error.

Comment: Have a look at the answer provided here, can you try returning View? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356403/null-tempdata-when-passing-data-from-controller-to-view-mvc

Comment: What I am confused about really is, why is this a temporary issue after a deploy? Why does restarting the site stop it? And, why is the error returned on the line it is?

Comment: Can you try returning a view once? Then we will see what is the issue. Also, add complete code of line `RedirectToAction`.